# sharpsvn - get list of all projects on subversion server

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I need to list all projects on a subversion server from sharpsvn. This is equivalent to command:

```
 wget http://me:@subversion-server/root/
```

I cannot find the function in sharpsvn api. Does the function exist?

**Update:**

Sorry for not being clean. I will give a real world example.

Consider www.apache.org and their SVN.

I need the list of all apache projects such as abdera, activeqm, ant, apr ... I can get the list by http at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ or by svn: `"svn list http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf"`.  Is the http method available through sharpsvn api? On my server the "svn list" method does not work (misconfigured?).

Comment: So.. Are you looking for a list of repositories, or a directory listing inside a repository? The confusion comes from using 'projects', and also by giving the `/root/` example url. Most Subversion urls are `http://server/svn/myrepos`

Answer (score 3):

SVN does not have "projects" at all. Only folders. So you are probably looking just for the folder list of the root of your repository!? If you are looking for all repositories on a single server: Those are not managed by subversion, so you have to get that information from somewhere else.

Comment: The information that I am looking for (and which is obtained by the above command) is returned by subversion. It is a piece of xml that contains list of projects (I didn't intentionally use word 'repository' because I saw the word used in at least in two different meanings). By project I mean the folder which contains 'trunk'. The folder with all projects cannot be read by the svn protocol, just by http as above (at least in my case). Therefore I am looking for a method which will get and parse that xml.